# Stop-Service not interating through each service

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to disable all Windows services (using a Win10 test VM) and go through each individually, to disable all unnecessary services based off services I'm using (web server, ftp, etc).

I was going to loop through it but basically ended up with similar syntax. I also tried to implement `Sleep-Timer` but I probably put it in the wrong place.

```
Get-Service | Where-Object {$_.Status -eq "Running"} | Stop-Service -Force
```

At least error messages for all of them. It's only showing error messages for the first two:

[image: error message]

Comment: You can use `foreach` loop for iteration and then you can stop each service inside the loop. But This is a very void question because you cannot stop certain services like RPC. So, get the list of services on which you want to operate.

Comment: I would also argue that you either need to list all services that you **don't** want to shutdown or list the services that you want to shutdown. Looping through all services and **trying** to stop them isn't a great way to go about things.

Comment: You are going to get errors as Windows cannot function with every service stopped. [This page](http://www.blackviper.com/service-configurations/black-vipers-windows-10-service-configurations/) goes into detail about what the services do and if they can be stopped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I was formatting the `foreach` loop was incorrect and eventually fixed it.

```
 $servicesArray = Get-Service | Where-Object {$_.Status -eq "Running"} | Select -Property Name

 ForEach ($service in $servicesArray)
 {
    Stop-Service $service -Force
 }
```

I also found an open source script that does it cleaner: https://vilimpoc.org/research/stop-all-services/

The link giving by James C. is one I will reference through my learning process of these services. Thank you all!